# Mockery test trait and mock method

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, mockery

I try to unit-test a trait with two methods. I want to assert the result of `foo` which calls another method inside the trait:

```
<?php
trait Foo {
    public function foo() {
        return $this->anotherFoo();
    }

    public function anotherFoo() {
        return 'my value';
    }
}

/** @var MockInterface|Foo */
$mock = Mockery::mock(Foo::class);
$mock
    ->makePartial()
    ->shouldReceive('anotherFoo')
    ->once()
    ->andReturns('another value');

$this->assertEquals('another value', $mock->foo());
```

I get the following result when I run `phpunit`:

```sh
There was 1 failure:

1) XXX::testFoo
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'another value'
+'my value'
```

Is this generally possible like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can directly mock a trait like that.  What does seem to work is to do the same thing but using a class that uses the trait.  So, for example, create a test `Bar` class that uses `Foo` and then make a partial mock of *that*.  That way you're working with a real class and Mockery seems happy to override the trait method.

```
trait Foo {
    public function foo() {
        return $this->anotherFoo();
    }

    public function anotherFoo() {
        return 'my value';
    }
}

class Bar {
    use Foo;
}

/** @var MockInterface|Bar */
$mock = Mockery::mock(Bar::class);
$mock
    ->makePartial()
    ->shouldReceive('anotherFoo')
    ->once()
    ->andReturns('another value');

$this->assertEquals('another value', $mock->foo());
```